# Cassandra Db in windows 7 xampp

Tags: windows, yii, cassandra, xampp

I need to store stock market data and stock graph datas for my site . so i am selecting two db's mongo and cassandra and i finalize cassandra db, i am using windows 7 , Xampp and i need to use this in yii. i am installing data stack it is working in cli and its also working in (localhost:8888) . so now how can i connect it in yii site .

> Is this requirement solvable? I need the steps to connect. Because diffrent site tells the different solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect a client to your php framework

PDO driver - https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-pdo/
A popular php driver - https://github.com/thobbs/phpcassa
The pdo driver also supports CQL, which is good if you are just getting started.

**note** The project appears to be dead, but there is a github fork of it with recent updates: https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/YACassandraPDO

phpcassa has lots of examples on how to get started in the [github page](https://github.com/thobbs/phpcassa). One thing to be aware of is that the example lists super columns, try to stay away from supper columns as they are somewhat deprecated.

The final option is to set up your cassandra server and host it inside of a webserver which can be queried (for example via rest) and this will give you access to more powerful java drivers, although the php drivers above should do the job.

Comment: i am using extension from the follwing link https://github.com/masumsoft/yii-cassandra-cql3 . but i am having the following error "cassandra\InvalidRequestException" .yii cassandra query where can i get it

Comment: @user2299204 Please add the full error to your question. Telling us the error is probably the most useful thing you can do. Also show me the code you use to run the query.

Comment: The error is :cassandra\InvalidRequestException
D:\xampp\htdocs\finance_casen\protected\extensions\yii-cassandra-cql3\Thrift\Base\TBase.php(206) i Am using the the following code:$query_result1 = Yii::app()->cassandra->cql3_query("CREATE TABLEusers(user_namevarchar,passwordvarchar,gendervarchar,session_token varchar,state varchar)");$query_result2=Yii::app()->cassandra->cql3_query("INSERT INTO users(user_name, password) VALUES ('saran', 'raja')");
$query_result = Yii::app()->cassandra->cql3_query("SELECT * FROM users");$rows = Yii::app()->cassandra->cql_get_rows($query_result);
print_r($rows);

Comment: i found the solution.the create table query run's every time after creating the table also.so first i run the create table query and delete it then run the insert query . its working fine in my yii framework